# GCP Logging log-based metric from folder-level logs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

In Google Cloud Logging (nee Stackdriver), can I create a [log-based metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics) for logs aggregated at folder/organization level?  I want to have a log-based metric for a certain audit event across many projects.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently supported. You can [export](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export) logs to a different project, but can't have metrics encapsulating more than one project.
If you think that functionality should be available, you can create a Feature Request at [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).